# Parse String to a Generic Type

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a String to a generic type such as:

```
Int16, Int32, Int64, Double, Boolean, DateTime, Guid, ...
```

I created the following which works fine for Ints and Booleans:

```
public static Boolean TryParse<T>(String source, out T value) {

  TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

  try {

    value = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(source);
    return true;

  } catch {

    value = default(T);
    return false;

  }

}
```

However, it is not working for Doubles, Dates, ...

Without using the generic TryParse I was able to make it work:

```
  List<String> values = new List<String> { "1", "true", "2.125", "C", "20-08-2016" };

  List<Object> parsed = new List<Object>();

  foreach (String value in values) {

    Int32 i;
    Boolean b;
    Double d;
    DateTime dt;

    if (Int32.TryParse(value,NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out i)) {
      parsed.Add(i);
    } else if (Boolean.TryParse(value, out b)) {
      parsed.Add(b);
    } else if (Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d)) {
      parsed.Add(d);
    } else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt)) {
      parsed.Add(dt);
    } else {
      String s = value;
      parsed.Add(s);
    }

  }
```

But as you can see I am passing a few parameters to each TryParse which seems to be needed specially for Doubles and DateTimes.

The problem is that in the system I am creating I am not sure of the type I will parse the string to so this is why I am using Generics.

How can I make this work?

**EXAMPLE**

Unit testing for parsing a double:

```
public void TryParse_ParseStringToDouble() {

  Double result;

  StringExtensions.TryParse("2040.345434", out result);

  Assert.Equal(result, 2040.345434);

}
```

With this I get an exception on TryParse:

```
2040.345434 is not a valid value for Double.
```

I think it is because I should use "2040,345434" on the machine I am working on ... But I would like this to work anyway ...

Comment: I tried `double` and your generic `TryParse<T>` works fine for me.

Comment: How do you use your version of `TryParse`? can you give an example?

Comment: http://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2015/february/convert-string-to-any-type-that-implements-tryparse-method/

Comment: @YacoubMassad Just added the test in my question.

Comment: In this case, `T` is already known at compile time. Why don't you create multiple non-generic overloads of `StringExtensions.TryParse`, one for each type?

Comment: That was just a simple test. In fact I am receiving Strings on an API and I need try parse them to a specific format.I do not know at what will I receive in those strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to convert you could use the following method.

```
public T ConvertToType<T>(string input)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
}
```

Usage:

```
string input = "06/23/2016";
DateTime date = ConvertToType<DateTime>(input);
```

Comment: Got the error "Input string was not in a correct format." when using your code and parsing the double "20.405"

Comment: Did you change the type? I just did the same test and it worked perfectly. "20.405" won't convert into `DateTime`. `double myDouble = ConvertToType<double>(input);`

Comment: Yes I did change the type ... Probably if you try "20,405" (Note the comma) you will get the same error I am getting with "20.405". No?

Comment: Type passing in an `IFormatProvider` to the `ChangeType` method. `new CultureInfo("en-US")` might be the one you want.

Comment: You could also type `Convert.ChangeType(input.Replace('.', ','), typeof(T));`

Comment: if you see in my initial question I have, after the generic TryParse code, a few examples using Double.TryParse, DateTimeTryParse where I needed to pass a few extra parameters ... This is what I am tyring to incorporate in my generic method. Is this done through the IFormatProvider?

Answer (score 0):

Same as Matt Rowland's but handles nullables.

```
 public static T ConvertToType<T>(object value)
 {
      var targetType = typeof(T);
      var conversionType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType) ?? targetType;
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType);
  }
```